# How do I store auth token after user login in vue js?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, browser, oauth-2.0, vuejs2

I am using vue js as a front end and after authenticating user from my appi built with laravel I am receiving a token which is supposed to send with every consequent request for authenticating the api.

But how should I store the token in the browser Securely?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad. So I'm gonna give a general answer.

Use `localStorage`to store the token.

```
localStorage.setItem('name','tokenValue'); // to store the token
localStorage.getItem('name'); // to getthe token value
```

A simple web search will give you all you need to know about localStorage. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#web-storage-disadvantages    
 I read this blog and found out that localstorage can be vulnerable to xss attacks.

Comment: Should I use cookie storage for storing the token or is there any other secure way around this as cookies are vulnerable to csrf attacks but as I am using laravel as a backend I think laravel provides csrf protection is that right??

Comment: If someone can get a token from your local-storage, he can also get the cookies. For security, you can do is make the token long, complex and encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Answer that I found here is very inefficient because localStorage is not assync so after login you would need to refresh entire page which is very bad UX to refresh single page app which I believe is what you develop since you use vue.

What I can suggest istead is localForage which is nothing more than assync localStorage. It is promise based and syntax looks very similiar to localStorage.

Example:

```
localforage.getItem('something', myCallback);
```

More info in its [docs](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).

And to send token in every request to backend you should use `vue.http.interceptors`.

Example:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next)  => {
  request.headers['Authorization'] = auth.getAuthHeader()
    next((response) => {
      if(response.status == 401 ) {
        auth.logout();
        router.go('/login?unauthorized=1');
      }
   });
});
```